# Why are 近く and 多く nouns?

Tags: grammar, conjugations, adjectives, adverbs, i-adjectives

The く-form of 近い and 多い can be used as nouns and adverbs.

For most adjectives, however, the く-form is only used as an adverb.

So why do these exceptions exist?

Comment: cf. http://id.nii.ac.jp/1284/00000586/, http://semlab5.sbs.sunysb.edu/~rlarson/jk11.pdf, http://www.gges.org/library/class1/docuclass1/soturon/Ando2006.pdf